# NetMQ (ZeroMQ) how to make "Brokerless Reliability (Freelance Pattern)" works

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I facing some problems with the example I got from the ZeroMQ Guide, looks like the class ZSocket and ZContext doesn't exist.
I'm totally new with ZeroMQ (just start lo learn) and I'm following the "[ØMQ - The Guide](https://zguide.zeromq.org/)". The first example about REQ-REP, which is very simple, worked well. But now I'm trying something more similar to my objective, the "[Brokerless Reliability (Freelance Pattern)](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/#Brokerless-Reliability-Freelance-Pattern)" and this one didn't work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with C# code, I created a new project, added NetMQ V4.0.1.6 via Nuget and copied the [server code](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/#Model-One-Simple-Retry-and-Failover) to my project. I got errors with ZContext and ZSocket. I already check the [API V3](http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:_start) and [API V4](http://api.zeromq.org/), they are clear different. The guide is totally based on version 3 and I'm using V 4. I didn't find any document about the changes or updates or equivalent function/classes/methods and I don't know how to convert the example to the NetMQ V4.

This is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using NetMQ;

namespace Examples
{
    static partial class Program
    {
        public static void FLServer1(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // Freelance server - Model 1
            // Trivial echo service
            //
            // Author: metadings
            //

            if (args == null || args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: ./{0} FLServer1 [Endpoint]", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("    Endpoint  Where FLServer1 should bind on.");
                Console.WriteLine("              Default is tcp://127.0.0.1:7780");
                Console.WriteLine();
                args = new string[] { "tcp://127.0.0.1:7780" };
            }

            using (var context = new ZContext())
            using (var server = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REP))
            {
                server.Bind(args[0]);

                Console.WriteLine("I: echo service is ready at {0}", args[0]);

                ZMessage message;
                ZError error;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (null != (message = server.ReceiveMessage(out error)))
                    {
                        using (message)
                        {
                            server.Send(message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (error == ZError.ETERM)
                            return; // Interrupted
                        throw new ZException(error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After long hours trying to understand that logic, I found a list of differences from ZeroMQ V3 and V4:
https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/wiki/Migrating-to-v4

Also, accidentally I found the example I was looking for:
https://github.com/NetMQ/Samples/tree/master/src/Brokerless%20Reliability%20(Freelance%20Pattern)/Model%20One